# System sent same question twice to me to review it again today

Tags: bug, review, review-audits

This is simply seems bug to me that system sent same question to me to review it again in a span of around 20 minutes.

[image: screenshot]

See in the comment with time (24 mins ago) wrote by system when system sent me first time to review then after span of 22 minutes system sent me again this question to review see above "TGMCians reviewed this 2 mins ago : Recommend Deletion". Here something buggy.

Why system allowed me to review same question two times and to make sure you that it was not audit anytime.

See here also something like buggy that system wrote same comment three times. It allowed me to click on "Recommend Deletion" three times. Why ??

[image]

Comment: I've actually had this a couple times the last time I reviewed. +1

Comment: I had this occurring twice when I did it through the VLQ review and then the 10K+ moderator tools, or was it when it came back to the VLQ again...

Comment: This happened to me when reviewing [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/5570421).  I reloaded the page and it showed the review as completed.